# R how to generate random yet easily invertible matrices

Tags: r, performance, benchmarking

I have a difficult `R` computation to do, and I have an option of 2 computers, called V and L, to run the code. V is supposed to be faster than L, but I did not experience this. So I decided to test it out.

As a simple test, I decided to ask them invert a 3000*3000 matrice 500 times, and record the time.

```
set.seed(123)
I=500
n=3000
time=matrix(NA,ncol=3,nrow=I)
for(i in 1:I){
t0<-proc.time()
x<-solve(matrix(runif(n^2),n))
mt1<-proc.time()
time[i,]<-(mt1-t0)[1:3]
}
```

The problem is that during a particular iteration, it got stuck. I don't know why but I suspect it is because the matrix generated was near singular. So I would like to improve the code. I can think of 3 ways:

1. make sure the matrix generated is easily invertible. But how do i enforce this??? Of course, any solution needs to be computationally inexpensive, otherwise the exercise becomes meaningless.
2. ask `R` to skip that iteration if `solve` takes too long? But again, how do I do that?
3. assign them a different computation task instead, any recommendation?

Comment: "1.make sure the matrix generated is easily invertible. But how do i enforce this" - don't make it random... BTW - there are standard ways to measure the perf. of a computer...Try Intel Burn-in or Prime95 etc

Comment: Could you make "random" triangular matrices? I'm guessing they are less likely to be singular. Or maybe band matrices?

Comment: You can generate 3000 column-vectors iteratively, ensuring that every vector is linearly independent from the previous ones. BUT, as Mitch says above, this is not the best way to measure performance.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: Just because each column is linearly independent of the others is not sufficient to ensure invertibility. It would reduce the probability of singularity but not eliminate it.

Comment: @DWin do you mean numerically or theorethically? Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Alternative_method_using_determinants

Comment: Oh, I'm reasonably confident. Here's a constructive (dis)-proof of your theory: take 3 randomly generated columns and make a fourth that is their sum. No two way pairings of them are likely to be collinear and yet the matrix is singular.

Comment: @DWin but the vectors in my theory are supposed to form a linearly independent set. The fourth vector must *not* belong in the linear span of the previous three. Maybe my english isn't good, but that's what I meant by "from the previous ones" (note plural) in my OC (original comment). :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: Your English is at least as good as mine. I think we agree, but now that you are proposing a serial test of collinearity for each added column with the matrix of prior columns, wouldn't this would be prohibitive from a computational feasibility standpoint?

Comment: @DWin We do agree. Your concern about feasibility is sound. A naive approach checking each vector against every other is certainly impractical. I don' know, but maybe you can save the span of the generated vectors (via gram-schmidt or something) and generate the next vector in the orthogonal complement... Just a guess. Anyway, better just make a triangular random matrix and ensure there are no zeros in the diagonal, and you're done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A random matrix is invertible with probability 1, meaning that, in practice, the probability of generating a singular (i.e. non-invertible) matrix is infinitesimally small.

Moreover, from the point of view of the algorithm that R uses to invert matrices, there is no such thing as an "easily invertible" matrix.  Either the algorithm succeeds, or it determines that a matrix is singular and fails.  But there is no scenario under which it tries "really hard" and takes a long time to invert a matrix.  It's a deterministic algorithm which either runs into a `0` (or a value smaller than some given epsilon), in which case if fails, or else it doesn't.

On which iteration do you get stuck?  Are you sure you are getting stuck on the inversion of the matrix, and it's not something like garbage collection that is taking a long time?

I can't reproduce the problem you describe.  Starting with random seed 123, I can invert 500 random 3000x3000 matrices in a row, using your code, without any significant timing discrepancies.  Can you find a random seed that generates a "hard to invert matrix" directly?

Comment: thanks for the statement that the inversion algorithm won't get stuck. I re-examined the time and found that the stucking has nothing to do with matrix inversion. My computer simply fell asleep.

Comment: Glad I could help.  BTW, you probably don't need 500 iterations to figure out which computer is faster.  10 (or even 1) will do just fine.  Unless there are other processes taking up CPU cycles, or R decides to garbage collect (which you can prevent by calling `gc()` before the test), the running time for inverting a 3000x3000 matrix won't vary much.

Comment: "My computer simply fell asleep" - comedy gold.